# Duplicate case in Switch

Tags: android

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        switch(requestCode)
        {
        case BOOK_SELECT: 
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String name = data.getStringExtra("SelectedBook");
                Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the book: " + " " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        case PEN_SELECT:
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                String name = data.getStringExtra("SelectedPen");
                Toast.makeText(this, "You have chosen the pen: " + " " + name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                break;
            }
        }

    }
```

here both the case are different I can not get it why it is showing

Comment: What is showing is it showing the tosts from the two cases.

Comment: no it is showing that boath the case is same

Answer (score 11):

From your title (which I assume is the error) check were your int variables are declared:

```
   int BOOK_SELECT = 0;
   int PEN_SELECT = 1; // If this was 0 you would get "duplicate case" error
```

You need to make sure they are unique

Comment: @Parth mark as answered if correct to help others :-) under the arrows on the left of the answer press the Tick so it goes green

Answer (score 1):

Are your `break;` statements meant to leave the function? If so, use `return;`

`break;` in the context of `case` is meant to stop it falling into the next `case` block.

Comment: his method is void he doesn't need to return;

Comment: Using `return;` without returning a value works with `void` and avoids the ambiguity between `break`ing the case and `break`ing the function.

Comment: I realise it works but because it is void, he should break the case not return it, that way it leaves the possibility of adding more code below the switch if it was needed later on

Comment: Fair enough, that depends how he answers the question in my post!

Answer (score 0):

The break is inside the enclosed if statement.